# Triple infinite integral, solving using gamma functions

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to do this practice problem for my final, but since there are no solutions I have no clue how to solve it.

[image]

My attempt was to try and let $u = x^2+y^2+z^2$, but since there are multiple variables I'm not sure how to find $du$.

Also, I know that the integral of $e^{-x} x^{-1/2}$ is equal to $\sqrt\pi$, so I'm trying to get it into that form as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measure of the set (sphere) $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2+z^2=u^2\}$ is given by $\frac{4\pi}{3} u^2$, hence the original triple integral equals:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{1-e^{-u^2}}{u^4}\cdot\frac{4\pi u^2}{3}\,du =\frac{4\pi}{3}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-e^{-u^2}}{u^2}\,du=\frac{4\pi\sqrt{\pi}}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: let $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, and take advantage of spherical symmetry.

Comment: What do you mean by spherical symmetry?

Comment: In other terms, consider transformation into spherical coordinates.

Comment: ... not quite: you don't need the integration over $\phi$ and $\theta$ because it's only a function of $r$.